# Upgrade from SQL Server 2008 to 2016 makes the query slower

Tags: sql-server, database-performance

We upgraded from SQL Server 2008 to 2016 and were checking the performance (execution time) of procedures. The newer SQL Server is installed on new and better hardware than the previous hardware as well. We expected the queries on newer hardware to run faster but surprisingly they run slower here.

Executing the query using different parameters some execute in same time as the previous SQL Server, but other takes older time multiplied by 2 to 10. I've tried comparing the execution plans on both the SQL Server machines. They are exactly the same.

The query I am trying is a stored procedure that does some string manipulation (making a select statement), executes it and return results.

The query on new hardware and SQL Server 2016 takes 2 to 10 times as long as on the old hardware and SQL Server 2008.

Are there any query performance techniques that I can try to execute the query faster on new software, hardware?

Comment: You should check the execution plans on both for machines, for each query.  If the original queries were not optimized at all, I can imagine something like this happening.

Comment: Did you upgrade in place or did you deploy new hardware with the new 2016 instance.

Comment: You can open the LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION property in the Database Scoped Configurations in Options tab. Sometimes it causes issue particular queries. At the same time FORCE_LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION hint in the stored procedure